# Error al querer incluir imagenes de Django al Carousel de Bootstrap

Tags: html, python, bootstrap, django

Estoy queriendo integrar imágenes desde Django en el Carousel de Bootstrap y directamente ni salen las imágenes. Adjunto el codigo del html:

```
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        {% for img in testimonios %}
        <div class="carousel-item
          {% if forloop.first %}
            active
          {% endif %}
        ">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ img.imagen.url }}" alt="">
        </div>  
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

views:

```
class HomeView(ListView):
"""All home view."""

template_name = 'home.html'
models = Testimonio
context_object_name = 'testimonios'
ordering = ('-created')

def get_queryset(self):
    """Return all rutines."""
    return Testimonio.objects.all()
```

models:
class Testimonio(models.Model):
"""Testimonio model."""

```
title = models.CharField('Titulo', max_length=150)

imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='testimonio/images/')

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    """Return title."""
    return self.title
```

Comment: Imposible darte una respuesta si no pones el codigo de la vista y no pones el nombre del modelo. Supongo quel modelo se llama img, y pasas esa variable corectamente en la vista.

Comment: @teurydiaz ahi adjunte la view y el model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error fue no incluir static y media en las urls.

El codigo que hay que poner es el siguiente:

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Despues del ] urlpatterns, ademas hay que importar:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```